# How to access standard PHP session data from inside CodeIgniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, native

I've got a Codeigniter project I'm working on, and using the CI Sessions (stored in a DB), but I need to check for a variable in another $_SESSION from another application (in the same cookie domain), but when I try, from the CI controller to use native PHP sessions to get this one bit of info ($_SESSION['blah']), it looks like CI is stripping out that global $_SESSION data.   Anyone know a way I can get at it?  I'd like to basically do something like this (with a little more error checking of course):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
      $this->session->set_userdata('usermap', $_SESSION['user_id']);
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you put `session_start()` in your `index.php?`

Comment: Oh, geez... I'm used to doing that up-front when I build a project from scratch.  Didn't think of doing that in CI.   I just put a session_start() in the single controller function that I needed it, instead of putting it in CI globally.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id')){
      $this->session->set_userdata('usermap', $_SESSION['user_id']);
}
```

You should use the session provided by CodeIgniter instead of mixing in native sessions.