# How to access codeigniter session using standard PHP $_SESSION?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a CI-based application that works as a portal to other apps in the same server(cookie domain).
But my other apps are not CI-based, can I access the CI-based SESSION using $_SESSION in the other app?

My problem is kinda similar to this link. but mine is just inverted.

[How to access standard PHP session data from inside CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755245/how-to-access-standard-php-session-data-from-inside-codeigniter)

Comment: Codeigniter Session based on encrypted Cookie. So you can not access them from another application. But if u really need u can use Native Php Session in your codeigniter.

Comment: in other words, i will have to add my CI-session to $_session first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an implement library of PHP $_SESSION in github, maybe it will be helpful.

[Native PHP Session for Codeigniter](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=codeigniter%20nsession%20github&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-Native-Session&ei=ZZBLUpKzGbGtiQfMk4CADQ&usg=AFQjCNEJkcDRawIBSLLNdVL2y13-88KpDw)

I have already used it in my project.